# Dynamic class type in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic

I'm writing a memory manager in C++ - that is, a class that allocates a lot of bytes from the heap, and then has allocate and deallocate functions for my program to use.

```
void* allocate(int size);
void deallocate(void*, int size);
```

This works fine, but what I don't like about it is that I need to do this to use it:

```
CClass* myobject = (CClass*) manager->allocate(sizeof(CClass));
```

So me question is, is there a way to pass the class type to the functions rather than using void pointers? This would remove the need for casting and the sizeof call, and it may also remove the need to pass the object size to the deallocate function.

Does anyone know of a better way I could be doing this?

Comment: templates ftw. BTW Do these classes have constructors and destructors?

Comment: You mean CClass? Its constructor and destructor won't be called when I use this method, I realise that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use template functions.

Simplified example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T* allocate() {
  return (T*) malloc(sizeof(T));
}

int main() {
  int *s = allocate<int>();
  *s = 42;
  return *s;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the standard `new` keyword? This seems redundant and yet unclean...

Comment: Fair enough, but `new T()` would have called the constructor as well, this was just meant to allocate it. The example was meant to just show templates.

Comment: The reason I don't want to use the new keyword is because it would defeat the purpose of a memory manager. This is also true of malloc, but I didn't want to point it out because Vlad gave me what I needed and I didn't want to be rude. My allocate function actually returns a pointer to some writeable memory in the manager's block, which does indeed mean the constructor doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload operator new, and operator delete for any specific user-defined type so that those operators use your allocator instead of the default heap allocator.